# C# Trying to add a service reference to a WCF service I built on a remote server. Get Access to the path '...' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I've been going crazy over this one! I've googled this problem and read everything that pertains to this but no luck! I've developed a WCF Service and a test web site to test this service with. These two work together very well (on my machine) when I add the service reference to the test web site, but when I publish the WCF Service to a remote machine and try to add *that service reference* I get an error that states:

> There was an error downloading '\SNMCDEVTEST\sslroot\EncompassService'.
>   Access to the path '\snmcdevtest\sslroot\EncompassService' is denied.

This is behind the SSL (versus wwwroot) part of the remote servers IIS. I have a self-signed certificate attached to the server and a new application pool attached to the WCF service. I've made sure that everyone has access to this folder, but I still keep on getting this error!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Steve

Comment: We can't do much without seeing your code.

Comment: What account do you have linked to the App Pool? You're _sure_ this user has appropriate permissions?